Hard cap creating calendars with Google Calendar API?
I'm trying to implement a feature with Google Calendar API, and wanted to know if there's a hard cap on how many calendars can be created. Looking at the Google documentation/support, I can only see the cap on a "short period" (that they don't specify how much time it is), and wanted to know if there was a general hard cap on it.
Thanks!

I think the limits are on calendar itself and not the api.
